# make table out of several files and combine into one matrix table

Tags: r

I have these files (https://github.com/learnseq/RNAseqcollection.git) that I want to merge(combine) the second column of each into one table with reference name. I have two issues: how to enforce column conversion from factor to another type (because I'm getting error when I try) and how to join them with shorter code.

I want this out put (for example one row of the output):

```
    Geneid      MCL1.DG MCL1.DI  MCL1.DK MCL1.LA MCL1.LC MCL1.LE MCL1.DH MCL1.DJ MCL1.DL MCL1.LB MCL1.LD MCL1.LF
1   100008567     0        0        0      0       0       0       0        0       0      0       0      0
```

I tried this:

```
files = list.files(path=".", pattern="MCL")
file1 = read.table("MCL1-DG.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-DG" ))
file2 = read.table("MCL1-DI.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-DI" ))
file3 = read.table("MCL1-DK.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-DK" ))
file4 = read.table("MCL1-LA.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-LA"))
file5 = read.table("MCL1-LC.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-LC"))
file6 = read.table("MCL1-LE.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-LE"))
file7 = read.table("MCL1-DH.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-DH"))
file8 = read.table("MCL1-DJ.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-DJ"))
file9 = read.table("MCL1-DL.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-DL"))
file10 = read.table("MCL1-LB.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-LB"))
file11 = read.table("MCL1-LD.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-LD"))
file12 = read.table("MCL1-LF.txt", col.names=c("Geneid","MCL1-LF"))


out.file = merge (file1, file2, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file2 <- merge(out.file, file3, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file3 <- merge(out.file2, file4, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file4 <- merge(out.file3, file5, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file5 <- merge(out.file4, file6, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file6 <- merge(out.file5, file7, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file7 <- merge(out.file6, file8, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file8 <- merge(out.file7, file9, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file9 <- merge(out.file8, file10, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file10 <- merge(out.file9, file11, by=c("Geneid"))
out.file11 <- merge(out.file10, file12, by=c("Geneid"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work quite well:

```r
files = list.files(path=".", pattern="MCL")

table_list <- lapply(X = files, FUN = read.table, header=TRUE)

combined <- Reduce(f = merge, x = table_list)
```

We first loop over the table names with `lapply` and read each one in, returning a list. By using `header=TRUE` we can avoid having to rename each one and instead deduce the column names from the first row of each file. Then we can use `Reduce` to repeatedly `merge` each table with the next one. `merge` is smart enough to assume that the shared column name is the thing we want to merge on, so we don't need to specify arguments there either.

I didn't download all the files but here's the output from running this code on the first 3:

[image: Better merged data frames]

Comment: Thank you @Dubukay ...can I convert the columns from factor to numeric or integer?

Comment: On my machine, all the columns are already numeric. Do they get read in as factors when you try it?

Comment: I suspect that things were getting read in as factors initially because reading in the header caused R to assume the columns were strings since the first row of the column is. When we don't read that first row in, the problem should disappear!

Comment: I just tried your code...it works flawlessly @Dubukay because when I tried my code they came out as factor, but your code they come as integer. Thank you so much, is there an easy way to convert the columns from one type into another.

Comment: @user432797 Sure, you should be able to use something like `combined$MCL1.DG <- as.character(combined$MCL1.DG)`. For more complicated things I'd recommend the `dplyr` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html

Comment: When I read your sophisticated code, I realized how primitive my coding is, I'm self learner and I try to reach level near yours, I open to any tip, thank you again @Dubukay

Comment: @user432797 We were all beginners once! And you have my admiration for being a self-learner - that certainly isn't easy. Just keep working on things that are interesting to you and don't be afraid of getting errors.

Comment: I have one more question @Dubukay, the table that was generated is a dataframe, how can I convert it into matrix without changing its appearance? is it good to use a data.matrix(DF)?

Comment: `data.matrix` should work, or maybe `as.matrix`. Matrices are trickier than data frames, however - you might want to convert that first column of "Gene ID" into rownames of the matrix rather than keeping it as a column of your matrix if you're running statistical tests on these genes.

Comment: this works? `samp2 <- samp[,-1]
rownames(samp2) <- samp[,1]`

Comment: That's exactly what I'd do :)